# Is "Professor X presents lecture Y this semester" right?

Tags: grammar, verbs

Is "Professor X presents lecture Y this semester" right or I should use verb "give" instead of "present"?

Here by a lecture I mean the normal lecture that takes one semester which is 4 months!

Thanks!

Comment: I'd call that a series of lectures. Google hits for << "present a series of lectures" -past >> and "give a series of lectures" are roughly in the ratio of 1 : 2. So I'd say this is largely a matter of opinion.

Comment: Again this question of yours seems off-topic. This site needs reasonable research to accompany questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) for `_v* a lecture`, where `_v*` is a wildcard that matches verbs. I got the following results:

- ~168 hits for "give* a lecture" (where "give" includes other forms of the word: gave, given, giving, etc.). Most of the matches used some form of "give".
- ~18 hits for "present* a lecture" (where "present" includes other forms of the word: presents, presented, presenting, etc.)

From these numbers, it's pretty clear that "give" is the most common form, but "present" is also used, so I wouldn't say it's wrong.

(Note that this answer only applies to *lecture* in the sense "an educational talk". In the sense of "a scolding", it would be wrong to say you "presented someone a lecture".)

Comment: But note that OP is possibly not talking about a single lecture, and preferred choice of verb might vary.